Sci-fi novel with spaceships that must be rotated precisely to reach the location safely
Many years ago, probably more than 20, I read a novel that involved interstellar voyage. It stuck in my mind and I would like to read it again, but I can't remember the title nor the author.
All I can remember is that the method of traveling involved an angle by which the ship was to be rotated precisely to reach the location safely.
The captain (or whoever was doing the manouver) had displayed in front of him a series of possible outcomes of the travel. These images represented himself, or slightly different copies of himself, as the travel could have outcomes in which the future was not exactly the same (think about the "many world interpretation" in physics or something like that). Some of these images were empty: those were the cases in which he would have died, the worst possible outcome of the travel.

Although it's not a novel but a novella, this is probably "Cascade Point" (1983), by Timothy Zahn.  In this story, starships travel via the "Colloton Drive", which involves moving the ship into an alternate kind of space, so that images of the protagonist appear:

In the eight years since the liner captain uniforms had appeared they had been gradually moving away from me along all four arms of the cross. Five more years, I estimated, and they would be far enough down the line to disappear into the mass of images crowded together out there. Whether my reaction to that event would be relief or sadness I didn't yet know, but there was no doubt in my mind that it would in some way be the end of a chapter in my life. I gazed at the figures for another minute... and then, with my ritual squeezing of the bruise accomplished, I let my eyes drift up and down the rest of the line.They were unremarkable, for the most part: minor variations in my appearance or clothing. The handful that had once showed me in some nonspacing job had long since vanished toward infinity; I'd been out here a long time. Perhaps too long... a thought the half-dozen or so gaps in each arm of the pattern underlined with unnecessary force. I'd told Bradley that ships like the Dancer rarely crashed, a perfectly true statement; but what I hadn't mentioned was that the chances of simply disappearing en route were something rather higher. None of us liked to think about that, especially during critical operations like cascade point maneuvers. But the gaps in the image pattern were a continual reminder that people still died in space. In six possible realities, apparently, I'd made a decision that killed me.

Also, as you say, the ship has to be rotated in the alternate space in order to move the ship in real space:

Taking another deep breath, I forced all of that as far from my mind as I could and activated the Dancer's flywheel.Even on the bridge the hum was audible as the massive chunk of metal began to spin. A minute later it had reached its top speed... and the entire ship's counterrotation began to register on the gyroscope set behind glass in the ceiling above my head.

...

[W]hat it all eventually boiled down to was that a yaw rotation of the ship here would become a linear translation when I shut down the field generator and we reentered normal space. The Dancer's rotation was coming up on two degrees now, which for the particular configuration we were in meant we were already about half a light-year closer to our destination. Another—I checked the printout—one point three six and I would shut down the flywheel, letting the Dancer's momentum carry her an extra point two degree for a grand total of eight light-years.


David, I think you found it! I don't know how to thank you, it was some years I was thinking about this novella (as you pointed out). You were very kind, and I must add, this site is a treasure! Thank you again, has a great day! :-)
